# Krusader and Putty not working on Ubuntu 22.04 Raspberry Pi Desktop

Tags: ssh, raspberrypi, putty, 22.04, krusader

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop on my RPi 4 and then installed Krusader and Putty. Both state "connection refused" when I try to start a session connection.
OpenSSH server is installed and running on all machines on the network, and both these applications worked on previous installs of 20.04.
Has anyone else experienced this? and does anyone have a solution please?
Note: CLI SSH commands work ... cannot understand why Krusader and Putty do not !?

Thanks for any help with this.
Patrick.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I fixed that by running putty as administrator. Run
$ sudo putty

This should fix the problem, however you need to do this every single time.

In my case I found that the problem was due to the font.
I fixed it by using this:

https://github.com/architectcom/-/wiki/ubuntu-22.04-install-putty%2C-with-error-message-%3A-%22unable-to-load-font-%22server%3Afixed%22

I hope this helps

Comment: Can you do this: